# how to update multiple ids with different value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

```
My form have multiple checkboxes in it (each with the code):
<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="<? echo $row['id'] ?>">
```

when user select id = 2 , 3 and 9 and submit the value. In my update php i am using following code to get selected value

```
echo "Check box test<pre>" ;
print_r($id); 
echo "</pre>";
if(!empty($_POST['id'])) {
foreach($_POST['id'] as $check) {
echo $check."\n";
}
}

// update data in mysql database 
 $sql="UPDATE table SET display = '2'  WHERE  id IN ($check)";
```

i am always getting last selected id updated like 9

but i am not getting result as i wanted like

```
$sql="UPDATE table SET display = '2'  WHERE  id IN (2,3,9)";
```

. please Help what to do. i am very new to php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing  nothing with `$check`, Make id like this

```
 $ids="";
 if(!empty($_POST['id'])) {
   foreach($_POST['id'] as $id) {
      $ids[] = $id;
   }
 }
 $check = implode(",", $ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are iterating the loop and `$check` will have latest value for the iteration.

```
foreach($_POST['id'] as $check) {
  echo $check."\n";
}
```

Why can't you try instead ?

```
$check[] = $_POST['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get a better understanding of `echo` and the diference between server-side and client-side.
What you are looking for is `implode`

```
if(!empty($_POST['id'])){
    $check = '(' . implode(',', $_POST['id']) . ')';
}
```